# How to fix twitter bootstrap buttons layout in IE7?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-7

I have 3 button in my form:

```
<form id="myform" class="form-horizontal" class="collapse in">
  <fieldset>
    <div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="place-of-birth">Место рождения</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="place-of-birth" name="place-of-birth" minlength="2" maxlength="80" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>    
    <div class="form-actions">
      <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-demo-search">Демо поиска</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn" id="clear">Очистить форму</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse" id="search" name="search" data-loading-text="Поиск...">Поиск</button>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/olilek/1)

On the same screen size, it looks awful in IE7 (2 lines, no margins):
[image: IE7]

When it is OK in Firefox:
[image: Firefox]

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This helps a little bit:
http://www.claystreet.com/sites/claystreet/dev/bootstrap/iebutton-fix/

But doesn't fix the square corners.

HTH